Using the name of a column as a parameter in Pyspark SQL query
On a particular DataFrame I have a SQL query that I want to use twice, once to generate daily results and once to get monthly results.  I can't just roll up the daily information because I have non-additive metrics like averages, distinct counts, etc.
SOURCE_BASIC_METRICS = """
select category,
    {date_field} as dt,
    count(distinct id) as unique_ids
from mytable
where 1=1
group by category,
    {date_field}
""";

mytable has a field called event_date and event_month.  I want to execute the query twice, like so.
dfBasicMetrics = spark.sql(SOURCE_BASIC_METRICS, date_field = "event_date");
dfBasicMetrics\
    .write\
    .parquet(DESTINATION_BASIC_METRICS + "/daily", mode = 'overwrite');

dfBasicMetrics = spark.sql(SOURCE_BASIC_METRICS, date_field = "event_month");
dfBasicMetrics\
    .write\
    .parquet(DESTINATION_BASIC_METRICS + "/monthly", mode = 'overwrite');

I'm new to parameterized queries, and I've been able to pass values, but haven't figured out how to pass an actual column name.  I couldn't get the parameter marker method to work, like this...
spark.sql("select :date_field, etc etc", args={"date_field": "event_date"})
The named parameters in curly braces is as close as I've gotten.  Would love any help using either method to be able to use an actual column name as the variable.
Thanks!

Parameters can only be used for values, not for table and column names. You need to use normal string formatting for dynamic column names.

I'm not sure but f-string potentially could be a solution for your problem.

To dynamically parameterize column names in Pyspark SQL queries, you can use string formatting to inject the column name directly into the query string before passing it to spark.sql()
Solution
SOURCE_BASIC_METRICS = """
SELECT category,
       {date_field} AS dt,
       COUNT(DISTINCT id) AS unique_ids
FROM mytable
GROUP BY category, {date_field}
"""

dfDailyMetrics = spark.sql(SOURCE_BASIC_METRICS.format(date_field="event_date"))
dfDailyMetrics.write.parquet(DESTINATION_BASIC_METRICS + "/daily", mode='overwrite')

dfMonthlyMetrics = spark.sql(SOURCE_BASIC_METRICS.format(date_field="event_month"))
dfMonthlyMetrics.write.parquet(DESTINATION_BASIC_METRICS + "/monthly", mode='overwrite')

